# In R, sample [n] unique IDs for whom the value of [column] equals zero

Tags: r, dataframe, random, dplyr

## Background

Here's `d`, an `R` dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b","c","d","d"), 
                gender = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1), 
                zip = c(48601,48601,NA,29910,54220,NA,44663),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It looks like this:

```
ID  gender    zip
 a       0  48601
 a       0  48601
 b       0     NA
 b       0  29910
 c       0  54220
 d       1     NA
 d       1  44663
```

## The Problem

I'd like to sample conditionally from `d`, but I'm getting tripped up on the details.

Specifically, I'd like to sample ...

- All the rows of a certain number (2, in this case) of unique `d$ID` ...
- ... in rows for which `d$gender` is zero

Phrased differently, I'm saying to R: "sample 2 distinct `ID`s who have `gender` = 0".

What I want is a dataframe `d2` that *could* look like this:

```
ID  gender    zip
 a       0  48601
 a       0  48601
 b       0     NA
 b       0  29910
```

Because it's sampling, of course, it could also look something like this:

```
ID   gender     zip
b         0      NA
b         0   29910
c         0   54220
```

The real dataset I'm working with has hundreds of thousands of unique `ID`; I want to sample from them (instead of just subsetting all of them) because it'll take too much memory to use them all in my analysis and, for statistical reasons, I don't need all those `ID` anyway.

## What I've tried

I've attempted things like this:

```
set.seed(123)
d2 <- sample(subset(unique(d$ID), d$gender==0), size = 2) %>% as.data.frame()
```

This runs, but the output is odd:

```
.
a
d
```

I've also seen several posts asking about conditional sampling (in fact I've made one myself before), but my parameters are slightly different and can't quite find what I need. I think I'm not too far from a solution, but it eludes me enough to ask for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to subset the 'ID' based on the 'gender' value of 0, get the `unique` elements, `sample` 2 of them, and create a logical vector with `%in%` on the 'ID' column in `filter` to filter those rows

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
    filter(ID %in% sample(unique(ID[gender == 0]), 2))
```

-output

```
  ID gender   zip
1  a      0 48601
2  a      0 48601
3  b      0    NA
4  b      0 29910
```

---

Or the similar concept in `base R`

```
subset(d, ID %in% sample(unique(ID[gender == 0]), 2))
   ID gender   zip
3  b      0    NA
4  b      0 29910
5  c      0 54220
```

Comment: The base `R` is always helpful, so thanks for that (dplyr stuff on big dataset sometimes gets wonky). I'll try this stuff and let you know. (Also do you ever sleep?)

Comment: @logjammin I have a followup question i.e. suppose if one of the ID have more than one gender i.e. 0 and 1.  Then, do you sample that ID

Comment: Short answer: no, don't sample that ID with more than one gender. In practice, though, it doesn't matter, as the dataset doesn't have any such "mixed" `ID`.

Comment: what if df is like this: `d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b","c","d","d", "a"), 
                gender = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1, 0), 
                zip = c(48601,48601,NA,29910,54220,NA,44663, NA),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun : What if, instead of `size = 2` for "how many rows to sample", I wanted to say something like `size = three times as many unique ID whose gender equals 1`?

Comment: @logjammin In those 3 times ID, does that include both ID having both gender

Comment: @TarJae, from what I can see, you've just added another row for `ID = a` whose `ZIP` now is `NA`. In that case, I'd still want that row to be included if R's `sample` function decided to include `ID` = a.

Comment: @akrun, no it wouldn't -- just `ID` whose `gender` is consistently 0.

Comment: @logjammin but your size will be based on gender == 1 unique IDs right

Comment: @logjammin Perhaps `d %>% filter({tmp1 <- unique(ID[gender == 1]); tmp0 <- unique(ID[gender == 0]); ID %in% sample(tmp0, size = length(tmp1) * 3)})`

Comment: Ah I see the issue -- you're basically asking "how do I treat any IDs who have a row of gender == 0 and a row of gender == 1?", right? Hmmm that's a tough one ... lemme think about it. No worries about this extra request, I'm fine just defining size == n for the sample function.

Answer (score 1):

We can `filter` for rows with `gender = 0`, sample two `ID`'s randomly and perform a join to keep all the rows of those `ID`'s.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  filter(gender == 0) %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 2) %>%
  left_join(d, by = 'ID')

#  ID gender   zip
#1  b      0    NA
#2  b      0 29910
#3  c      0 54220
```

Comment: This is really novel and works great, Ronak -- I didn't know about `slice_sample`. Quite readable, too, which I like as a novice. Thanks very much for it. I prefer the base R solution above for now, but I think your code will be very helpful to me and others in the future. Cheers.